# Removing characters after last alpha character (if exist) in url in PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm redoing a website and on this website there are two types of URL such as:

```
http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/one-friend-url-040569485.php
http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/one-friend-url.php
```

I need to get only `one-friend-url` without the extension `.php` or `-040569485.php` in any of the above situations, so I can submit the `one-friend-url` to be searched in mySQL.

So if the URL does not have a `-040569485.php` it just removes the `.php` extension, otherwise removes the `-040569485.php` from the URL.

What would be the best way to do this (php, regex or `.htaccess`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the regex if you need it in the format between "subcategory/" and ".php" with the numbers as optional

```
"subcategory/(.*?)(?:-?\d*?)\.php"
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly, just had to add a "\" escape delimiter: "subcategory\/(.*?)(?:-?\d*?)\.php".

When testing I came across a third possible URL, which could come without the ".php" extension previously removed by the htacess, in which case it would then have to leave the ".php" extension as optional.

The final regex looks like this:"subcategory\/(.*?)(?:-?\d*?)?(\.php)?$"